# ESP32-CAMERA + CV2 python

Tags: python, arduino, камера, cv2, esp32

Я хочу получать картинку с камеры esp32 через питон. Я нашёл куда она выводится *http://мой-айпи/stream*. Сам в браузере проверил что всё работает, на всякий вышел с сайта, с питона получаю от туда инфу этим кодом -

```
import cv2

capture = cv2.VideoCapture('http://мой-айпи/stream')
print(capture.read())
while True:
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    cv2.imshow("Camera", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Но он просто бесконечно грузит...

```
 PS F:\VSCpj> & c:/Users/Лев/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe f:/VSCpj/rabota.py
```

[image: ФОТО]

UPD: Как выглядит сам сайт:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я за это ничего не знаю, но как тебе картинка будет выводиться в терминал?

Comment: Я что то сказал про терминал? Он должен открыть интерфейс а он не чего не грузит, в терминале так же не чего нет.

Comment: Код использует cv2.VideoCapture, что указывает на то, что он зависит от библиотеки OpenCV. Убедитесь, что у вас установлена OpenCV (pip install opencv-python).
В строке `http://мой-айпи/stream` вероятнее всего, ошибка. IP-адреса обычно не имеют встроенных сервисов потоковой передачи. Вам понадобится URL-адрес конкретной камеры или источника потока.

Comment: cv2 есть. А вот ошибка в строке возможно